# In the scikit learn implementation of LDA what is the difference between transform and decision_function?

Tags: scikit-learn

I am currently working on a project that uses Linear Discriminant Analysis to transform some high-dimensional feature set into a scalar value according to some binary labels.

So I train LDA on the data and the labels and then use either `transform(X)` or `decision_function(X)` to project the data into a one-dimensional space.

I would like to understand the difference between these two functions. My intuition would be that the `decision_function(X)` would be `transform(X)` + `bias`, but this is not the case.

Also, I found that those two functions give a different AUC score, and thus indicate that it is not a monotonic transformation as I would have thought.

In the documentation, it states that the `transform(X)` projects the data to maximize class separation, but I would have expected `decision_function(X)` to do this.

I hope someone could help me understand the difference between these two.

Answer (score 1):

LDA projects your multivariate data onto a 1D space. The projection is based on a linear combination of all your attributes (columns in X). The weights of each attribute are determined by maximizing the class separation. Subsequently, a threshold value in 1D space is determined which gives the best classification results. `transform(X)` gives you the value of each observation in this 1D space `x' = transform(X)`. `decision_function(X)` gives you the log-likelihood of an attribute being a positive class `log(P(y=1|x'))`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer the question. The only question I am left with then is that according to the source code,  `decision_function(X)` is proportional to the distance to the hyperplane, but if `transform(X)` describes this hyperplane, one would expect the AUC of these two functions to be the same right?